# add_disk() hangs on insmod

Tags: linux-device-driver, insmod

I am writing a Linux block device driver and I have a lot of the initialisation stuff working. However, when I finally call `add_disk()`, the module hangs during `insmod`.

The offending snippet is here:

```
set_capacity(gendisk, dev->nsectors);
add_disk(gendisk);

//this line is never reached
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be caused by setting the capacity with `set_capacity()` *before* adding the disk. According to [this mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/linux.enbd.general/2002-10/msg00177.html), `add_disk` should be called on a gendisk with `gendisk->capacity = 0`, otherwise it hangs in `check_partition()`.

The following appears to work:

```
set_capacity(gendisk, 0)
add_disk(gendisk);
set_capacity(gendisk, dev->nsectors);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The `add_disk()` is not stuck but when I `dd` to the device, I got `No space left on device` error message.